# Why this code is not making a border under the nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a simple thin border under my nav bar which gets a bit thicker only under the link which i hover. I tried doing this using the following code but it doesn't work for some reason. How do I make it work?

```
#top-menu ul li a
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    max-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    bottom-border: rgb(0,0,0) solid 2px;
}

#top-menu ul li a:hover
{
    bottom-border: rgb(0,0,0) solid 4px;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting 2px border without mouse hover?

Comment: Paste some HTML code. www.jsfiddle.net is a good way to share code.

Comment: @Gendarme The better way would be to include an executable code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `border-bottom` not `bottom-border`

Comment: now im wishing i were dead :D this is ultra-LOL. but im a beginner in html&css so wudn't commit suicide just yet :P

Comment: Nah, don't worry, these things happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the navbar the 2px bottom border.

Give your nav links a 2px bottom border and set it to transparent or the color of the navbar (this will make the border appear to be non-existent).

When hovered over the nav link, change the nav link border color to match the nav border.

This will give the impression that the border is thicker for that one link.